# prove or disprove in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ decomposition of real integer to 2 elements with the same norm is unique up to multiplying by unit

Tags: number-theory, normed-spaces, gaussian-integers

let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$such that a=bc and say $|b|=B$ and $|c|=C$ . prove or disprove, there is no other decomposition such: $a=de ,|d|=B,|e|=C$
up to multiplying b and c by unity.

**Edit**: this claim is not true for complex number, but is it for reals? prove it!

Comment: What have you tried?
Please give a bit more context.
It is not just a site for uploading your homework.

Comment: This is related to the problem of determining the number of ways a given integer can be written as a sum of two squares. Search the site. Counterexamples exist. One way is it to use powers of $(1+i)$. Another to select $a$ that is a product of more than one prime, all $\equiv1\pmod4$.

Comment: Anyway, you should study [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) for tips about how to improve your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't hold for real number either:
counterexample: $25=(4+3i)(4-3i)=5*5$ yet $(4+3i)$ has the same norm as $5$, as well $(4-3i)$ and $5$.

Answer (score 0):

We can easily find a counterexample by finding two non-associates with the same norm, such as $1+7i$ and $5+5i$. Then, all we need is $$(1+7i)(x) = (5+5i)(y)$$
This yields $$\frac{y}{x} =\frac{1+7i}{5+5i} = \frac{4+3i}{5}$$
so by choosing $x = 5$ and $y = 4+3i$, we see that $$(1+7i)(5) = (5+5i)(4+3i)$$ which serves as a counterexample, since $|1+7i| = |5+5i|$ and $|5| = |4+3i|$, yet neither are associates.

Comment: May I ask, Can you find a counterexample if we try to decompose  real integer?

Comment: That's not possible, since for real integers $|a| = |b|$ means that $a = \pm b$, and so they differ by a unit.

Comment: no I mean:
let a be a real integer.
I want to see a counterexample for the decomposition claim I made. meaning the decomposition can be complex. but the the original number is real.

Comment: There are no counterexamples, the statement is true if $a$ is real. You can see this by looking at the prime decomposition of a real number over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: can you prove this claim?